# org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ChecksumFailureException after deleting m2 folder

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, pom.xml

I tried cleaning m2 folder then working application is throwing below error.

I tried, Recleaning the m2 folder, deleted branch and cloned again but I am facing same issue. Can anyone please help on this.

Thank you in advance.

Error Log :

```
[WARNING] Checksum validation failed, expected <!doctype but is 74a0061f89255bc52ee21eb07944fe42518a97ad from Spring plugin alt repo for https://repo.spring.io/ui/native/plugins-release/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.7.0/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.7.0.pom
[WARNING] Could not validate integrity of download from https://repo.spring.io/ui/native/plugins-release/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.7.0/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.7.0.pom
org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ChecksumFailureException: Checksum validation failed, expected <!doctype but is 74a0061f89255bc52ee21eb07944fe42518a97ad
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ChecksumValidator.validateExternalChecksums (ChecksumValidator.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ChecksumValidator.validate (ChecksumValidator.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$GetTaskRunner.runTask (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run (RunnableErrorForwarder.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:628)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtifact (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:262)
    at org.apache.maven.project.ProjectModelResolver.resolveModel (ProjectModelResolver.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.project.ProjectModelResolver.resolveModel (ProjectModelResolver.java:242)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParentExternally (DefaultModelBuilder.java:1070)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParent (DefaultModelBuilder.java:846)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build (DefaultModelBuilder.java:337)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build (DefaultProjectBuilder.java:448)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build (DefaultProjectBuilder.java:414)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build (DefaultProjectBuilder.java:377)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.collectProjects (DefaultGraphBuilder.java:414)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.getProjectsForMavenReactor (DefaultGraphBuilder.java:405)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.build (DefaultGraphBuilder.java:82)
```

> Pom :

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Issue was with settings.xml
added to solve above issue

```
<repository>
  <id>central1</id> 
  <name>Central Repository</name>
  <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>  
  <layout>default</layout>
<snapshots>
   <enabled>false</enabled>
</snapshots>   
</repository>
```